# Base vs sales quota correlation and fairness

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, salary, ethics

**This is a list of sales reps in my company**

- 4.5 yr in company $35K base $50K quota sales rep.
- 4 yrs in company $35K base  $50  quota sales rep.
- 4.5 yr in company $55K base $2 MIL quota sales rep.
- 2 months in company $45K base  $75K quota enterprise sales rep
- 2 months in company $35K base and $60K quota enterprise sales rep.

How can they correlate the base vs quota and $2MIL vs the others and have such a drastic difference between each representative?

They have a larger book of business, however do not receive additional resources to manage, and have the same resources as others, and actually the manager hands out accounts to whomever she chooses and are not fairly distributed.

Can someone provide their expertise and opinion on the situation above?

Comment: Is there a question here?  I'm afraid that I don't understand what you are saying or what you are asking.

Comment: I added some formatting, although the question still needs some work to be clear.

Comment: What value are the products behind the sales? If one is selling something that retails for $500K then getting $2 Million in sales is only 4 sales compared to getting $50K in sales of something that retails for $500 that requires 100 sales to get to the quota.

Answer (score 3):

A lot goes into setting sales quotas, not just seniority with the company. One very important factor is each rep's territory and account assignments. It's often very hard to understand that factor even if you are the sales VP. It's often impossible if you're in another department trying to figure out how things work in sales.

Believe me when I say that competent sales reps are exceedingly good at managing these sorts of expectations, and can look out for their own interests.

For example, if the company sells fiber optic strands, one customer might be an equipment manufacturer making 10-meter fiber connectors, and another customer might be a trans-Pacific-ocean communications provider. The rep handling the second account should indeed have much higher expectations for sales volume.

It's not wrong or uncommon in a rapidly growing company for the two or three most productive sales people to receive the highest compensation of anyone, executives included.